# generate QR code to open facebook app to my business page

Tags: android, iphone, facebook

I want to generate a QR code to open the Facebook app to show my Facebook page on both android and iPhone

I found the urls it needs to be but is different for android and iPhone so was seeing if anyone knows if there is a url that works on both android and iPhone to open the Facebook app to my Facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

Whats the url you got?
I never heard about facebook having different domains for ios and android.

Comment: I did have fb://page/1565260483695761 and it worked on android and ios was fb://page?id=1565260483695761 . I think I have just found a url that works on both android and ios. I now have fb://profile/100063785940192 and I tested it on android and ios and it opens the app on both platforms after scanning the QR code

Comment: Well problem fixed then ^^

Just for anyone who ever stumbled over this problem aswell, maybe mark your command as a answer or put the url in your question as an answer.

Comment: I just posted the comment as a answer, hopefully others can see it as the answer and helps others who want to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I found a url that works on both android and ios. I now have fb://profile/pageid and I tested it on android and ios and it opens the app on both platforms after scanning the QR code